# Practical Limits of ElasticSearch + Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, elasticsearch, limits

I am planning on using ElasticSearch to index my Cassandra database. I am wondering if anyone has seen the practical limits of ElasticSearch. Do things get slow in the petabyte range? Also, has anyone has any problems using ElasticSearch to index Cassandra?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See [this thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Best-performances-of-Elastic-Search-in-various-scenarios-td2820238.html#a2838194) from 2011, which mentions ElasticSearch configurations with 1700 shards each of 200GB, which would be in the 1/3 petabyte range. I would expect that the architecture of ElasticSearch would support almost limitless horizontal scalability, because each shard index works separately from all other shards.

The practical limits (which would apply to any other solution as well) include the time needed to actually load that much data in the first place. Managing a Cassandra cluster (or any other distributed datastore) of that size will also involve significant workload just for maintenance, load balancing etc.

Comment: Thank you DNA for your response. It was quite helpful.

Answer (score 13):

[Sonian](http://www.sonian.com) is the company kimchy alludes to in that thread.  We have over a petabyte on AWS across multiple ES clusters.  There isn't a technical limitation to how far horizontally you can scale ES, but as DNA mentioned there are practical problems.  The biggest by far is network.  It applies to every distributed data storage.  You can only move so much across the wire at a time.  When ES has to recover from a failure, it has to move data.  The best option is to use smaller shards across more nodes (more concurrent transfer), but you risk a higher rate of failure and exhorbitant cost per byte.

Answer (score 0):

AS DNA mentioned, 1700 shards, but it is not 1700 shards but there are 1700 indexes each with 1 shard and 1 replica. So it is quite possible that these 1700 indexes are not present on single machine but are split around multiple machines.
So this is never a problem

Answer (score -1):

I am currently starting working with Elisandra (Elasticsearch + Cassandra)

I am also, having problems to index Cassandra with elasticsearch. My problem is basically the node configuration.

Doing `$ nodetool status` you can see `Host ID` and then ruining:

`curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state/?pretty=true`

You can check that one of the `node:` is the same name as `Host ID`

Comment: this not an answer